# {a, b} ∩ {c, d} = {∅} true or false?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

since {a, b} and {c, d} have no common elements, then does {a, b} ∩ {c, d} = {} ? But from what I've read, {} is not equal to {∅}, so the statement should be false? I think it is false but I am not so sure.

Comment: It is false, since $\{\varnothing\}$ has a single element.

Comment: Yes. It is the empty set, often written as $\emptyset$. So the statement is false, because $\{\emptyset\}$ has one element.

Comment: Assuming that $a,b,c,d$ are distinct values and none are a relabel of another it is false.  $\{\emptyset\} \ne \emptyset$. (but $\emptyset = \{\}$).  But $\emptyset$ and $\{\}$ are a set with no elements in it.  $\{\emptyset \}$ is a set with one element in it; the one elements is $\emptyset$.  It is important to understand the distinction.  So, yes, the statment is false and your statement, $\{a,b\}\cap \{c,d\} = \{\}$ is correct.  (As is the statement $\{a,b\}\cap \{c,d\} = \emptyset$.)

Answer (score 1):

> since {a, b} and {c, d} have no common elements, then does {a, b} ∩ {c, d} = {} ?

Yes, it does.

$\{\}$ is a set which has no elements inside it.  Another way of writing it is $\emptyset$.  $\emptyset$ and $\{\}$ are two ways of writing the same thing.

> But from what I've read, {} is not equal to {∅}

Indeed.

$\{\emptyset\}$ is a set that has inside it *one* elment:  The empty set.  The empty set, despite not having anything inside it, is not nothing.  It is a thing with nothing inside it.  So $\{\emptyset\}$, which has something inside it, is not the same as $\emptyset$ or $\{\}$ which have nothing inside them/it.

Furthermore, the thing that is inside it, $\emptyset$, is  neither in $\{a,b\}$ nor in $\{c,d\}$ so it can't be in the intersection of $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$.

> so the statement should be false?

Indeed it is.

Answer (score 0):

Think of $\varnothing$ not as nothing, but a box with nothing inside it. Then, the intersection of $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$ can't be $\{\varnothing\}$ because $\varnothing$ isn't in either of the sets- they don't have any boxes.

(yes, I'm aware you can think of the integers as sets as well)

Comment: "(yes, I'm aware you can think of the integers as sets as well)" Yes, one can.  But that'd have nothing to do with the gyst of your argument and wouldn't in any way counter or enlighten your answer.  So anyone pointing it out is being pointlessly pedantic at best.

Comment: Oh... I see.  $a,b,c,d$ can be boxes themselves.  but your sentence "they don't have any boxes" could be false if $a,b,c$ or $d$ are boxes.  But supposedly none of them is an *empty* box.....